# Certification or Course equivalent to OSWE?

Tags: certification

Is there any certification which focuses specifically on web application penetration, CWE issues and code analysis like Offensive Security Web Expert (OSWE) does? OSWE is not available online and it is not feasible for me to attend until they organise it in my home country :D. But if there is a way which I am not aware of, please let me know.

Why I am taking reference is because, as everybody says on different forums, offensive security courses are practical and gives you real insight in things rather than just theories. Correct me if I have wrong impression of anything :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Security Certifications](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/web-security-certifications)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that such question is a good fit for this website but anyway...

I have heard good things about [eLearnSecurity](https://www.elearnsecurity.com/certification/) certifications which seems to be the de-facto alternative to the eternally """soon-to-be-published-but-not-ready-yet""" OSWE.

However, they do not seem to have yet a lot of recognition in job offers and last time I checked the certification exam was one week long, making it hardly compatible with a full-time job (I hope and guess that sometime they will change this. Yes you can do your exam during your vacation, but in case of a technical issue during the exam you are screwed.).